# CKEditor 5 - Angular 7 : object ngModel binding with sub childs problem

Tags: angular, ckeditor, angular7, angular8, ckeditor5

**1- First here is my codes:**

---

**ListPagesComponent:**

```
export class ListPagesComponent {
    public model = {
            id: -1,
            actif: 0,
            link: '',
            htmlContent: {
                fr: '',
                en: ''
            },
            title: {
                fr: '',
                en: ''
            }
        };    
    updatePage() {
                this.model = {
                    id: -1,
                    actif: 0,
                    link: 'my-link',
                    htmlContent: {
                        fr: 'Salut tout le monde',
                        en: 'hello welcome'
                    },
                    title: {
                        fr: 'title1',
                        en: 'title2'
                    }
                };
                console.log(this.model);
            }
}
```

**listpages.component.html - CKeditors in the same page:**

```
 <ckeditor name="content" 
    [editor]="editor1" 
    data=" " 
    (ready)="onReady($event) 
    [config]="editorConfig" 
    [(ngModel)]="model.htmlContent[langs.fr]">
    </ckeditor>

<ckeditor name="content" 
[editor]="editor1" 
data=" " 
(ready)="onReady($event)" 
[config]="editorConfig" 
[(ngModel)]="model.htmlContent[langs.en]">
</ckeditor>
```

---

**2- explanation of the issue:** 
when I click on a button who perform the execution of **updatePage()** , I expect to have as a result in the **console** : the correct new values of the updated htmlContents of frensh and english langages like :

```
actif: 0
htmlContent:
en: "<p>hello welcome</p>"
fr: "<p>Salut tout le mond</p>" <==== THE Expected Result
id: -1
link: "my-link"
title: {fr: "title1", en: "title2"}
```

the problem is that the given result is:

```
actif: 0
htmlContent:
en: "<p>hello welcome</p>"
fr: "<p>hello welcome</p>"   <==== THE ISSUE IS HERE 
id: -1
link: "my-link"
title: {fr: "title1", en: "title2"}
```

---

I hope my issue is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue : 
to be honest, I'm not sure if it is a **CKEditor5 Multi-instances cycle life bug** or **not** , but to resolve the problem, I just created a new component for reuse wich contains **one** instance of CKEditor component, and i passed to it an Input/output string property to make differences between different langages content (FR, EN etc..), and I just used this component in the parent wich contains the modal with the editor..
so this is my code solution :

---

the new added **HTMLEditorComponent** :

```
export class HTMLEditorComponent implements OnInit {
    /** Global Props **/
    public editor1 = DecoupledEditor;
    @Input() content: string;
    @Output() contentChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

    langs = {
        fr: 'fr',
        en: 'en',
    };
    /** editor configuration **/
    public editorConfig = {
        placeholder: 'Ecrire votre contenu ici!',
    };

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    /**
     * Init Global Page Editor
     * @param editor
     */
    public onReady(editor) {
        this.initEditor(editor);
    }

    /**
     * Init editor ui & toolbar
     * @param editor
     */
    private initEditor(editor) {
        editor.ui.getEditableElement().parentElement.insertBefore(
            editor.ui.view.toolbar.element,
            editor.ui.getEditableElement(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Update out changes
     */
    onChange() {
        console.log(this.content);
        this.contentChange.emit(this.content);
    }
```

**its view htmleditor.component.html:**

```
<ckeditor name="content"
          [editor]="editor1" data=" " (ready)="onReady($event)"
          [(ngModel)]="content"
          [config]="editorConfig"
          (ngModelChange)="onChange()"
></ckeditor>
```

**the parent component ListPagesComponent :**

```
export class ListPagesComponent implements OnInit {

// other codes here ...

/** List of available extensible langages **/
    langs = {
        fr: 'fr',
        en: 'en',
    };
/** Page Editor props **/
    page: Page = new Page();
    selectedLanguage: string = this.langs.fr;

// other codes here ...
// other codes here ...
/**
     * Modifier Page
     */
    updatePage() {
        this.showAddModal();
        //  update request
    }
// other codes here ..
// other codes here ..
}
```

**and this is how I used my HtmlEditorComponent in the parent ListPagesComponent html view:**

```
// for frensh language
<app-htmleditor [(content)]="page.htmlContent[langs.fr]"></app-htmleditor>
// for English language
<app-htmleditor [(content)]="page.htmlContent[langs.en]"></app-htmleditor>
```

I hope my solution is good for whose uses CKeditor5 :).